Ex. 3.2.2 of Qing Liu: Open immersion into locally Noetherian scheme is of finite type
The definitions are as follows: A scheme is locally Noetherian if the sections over every affine open subset form a Noetherian ring. A morphism $f:X\to Y$ is of finite type if:

It is quasicompact (i.e. the inverse image of each affine open is quasicompact: For each open covering there exists a finite subcovering. Equivalently the inverse image of each affine open is a finite union of affine subschemes) and
for each affine open $V\subseteq Y$ and affine open $U\subset f^{-1}(V)$ the ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)\to \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is of finite type i.e. makes the second into a finitely generated algebra over the first.

I've proved that it is quasicompact. I'm stuck with the second condition which seemed to be obvious. The ring $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$ is Noetherian and also $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ can be proved to be Noetherian. Does this suffice to show that it is of finite type? I looked over the internet and in my books and I didn't find that statement, despite it seems to have some importance.

No, a homomorphism between two noetherian rings is not automatically of finite type. For example, the quotient field $\mathbb{Q}$ of the noetherian integral domain $\mathbb{Z}$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.
Now to your actual question. Immersions are always locally of finite type (see for example Locally closed immersions are locally of finite type ). The crucial point is that open immersions are locally of the form $A \to A_{f}$ for an $f \in A$. And $A_{f}$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra (regardless of whether $A$ is noetherian).
So in fact the only thing that needs to be shown here is quasi-compactness, which you already did.
